# What are the possible values in the AfterTargets when I publish my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, publish

I want to execute an action after the publish. The `MsDeployPublish` do nothing, and `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage` execute before the files been copied to the publish folder.

So, I need the target that runs after files been copied and, if possible, the complete list of values possible.

Comment: Please expound your question.